# Suddenly a NoClassDefFoundError when running Glassfish from NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I have been working on a demo project all day and everything went just fine.

Suddenly (and, as it seems, unrelated to any of my actions) my application fails with a NoClassDefFoundError somewhere in the CDI internals. Strangely it worked before but I just cannot get it to work again.

I am using a rather fresh NB 6.9.1 install without any modules. I launched my Java Web application simply by clean+build and then run menu items.

The non-default setup is this:

I added two JARs from the Jersey project to the Library folder of my project:

jersey-bundle-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
jersey-view-client-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar

I removed the restlib libraries added by Glassfish.

I set class loader delegate to false in sun-web.xml:

as described by the Jersey docs.

That all worked fine up to a sudden point.

Can anyone provide a clue where I could at least start investigating?

Comment: It might be good to include the name of the class that has no def (and some of the lines off the top of the stack tace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing (everything works until NoClassDefFoundError emerges) happened to me once in a while on other projects as well.

The solution is to remove .netbeans/6.9/var/cache and restart NetBeans. I suspect that the culprit is corrupted index for NetBeans' custom classloader.

Comment: Thanks - will take me a while until I can check this out. I'll then 'check-mark' the answer.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. Deleting .netbeans/6.9/var/cache/index seems to be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Took me some time, but here is the best way I see to solve the problem: http://www.nordsc.com/blog/?p=574

Comment: could not see the solution at your link .. Could you clarify how you solved ?

Comment: sorry, lost backup when I moved blogs. That's why the link is broken. Anyhow - that solution did also not work.

Comment: oh.. do you have any idea right now about how to fix that ? :) really stuck with that right now...